# Generate SCORM for moodle from PHP

Tags: php, moodle, scorm

We have some instructions (text/image/videos) and some trainings build on PHP. We also have a Moodle working and we wanted to generate some SCORMs from this php application.

Is there any library, or instruction to achieve that?

Any help or clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the resource http://www.adlnet.gov and especially at this document: http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/SCORM-Users-Guide-for-Programmers?type=technical_documentation

It contains information about building and embedding resources into SCORM package.